# How to change the 1st letter of the string?

Tags: python

Change the 1st letter of the world Hello which is "H" to "X"

```
astring = ("Hello World")
```

result:

```
astring = ("Xello World")
```

Comment: Cut the string in two parts, then join the second part to an `'X'`.

Comment: Why the parentheses around the string?

Answer (score 1):

```
astring = "X" + astring[1:]
```

This slices the string and adds the new start in the desired position

More info on slicing can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

And you can just think of strings as immutable lists

Answer (score 0):

In Python, strings are immutable. "Immutable" means that they cannot be changed once they are assigned, only deleted.

You must make a new string. If the new string variable has the same name as the old string variable, it will be overwritten.

Comment: You can't say if the string will be overwritten, that's an implementation detail.  It might not even be garbage collected if there is another reference to the same string object, for example.  About all you can say is if the same name is used to refer to the new object then the reference count on the old object will be decremented.

Comment: When I said that the name would be overwritten, I meant that the string variable would now point to a different object in memory. Whether the string object itself is removed is of course up to how garbage collection is handled. Should have been a bit clearer, sorry about that!

That said, the concept of the nature of the variable, and its relation to the object in memory is too low level for a question where OP is clearly still a beginner. It's a lot better here to just use the abstraction that the string is overwritten, and let the OP learn what's actually going on under the hood later.

Answer (score 0):

```
astring = ("Hello World")
astring = "X" + astring[1:]
```

Comment: Why the parentheses around the string?

Comment: It is not necessary but I am used to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = ("Hello World") 
string = string.replace("H","X")
print(string)
```

The replace() method will do exatly what it suggests: replace the letter in the first speech marks (H) with that in the second (X)!